# Change color of line at runtime like microsoft paint in cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have a scene where I have few colored buttons and upon clicking on that colored button's respective colored line should be drawn in cocos2d. Please help me out with this.

I have tried passing different colors in `-(void)draw` function but that doesn't work. What I want is like MS Paint where user can have different color selction whereas I have put few color buttons.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't think of answer for you directly you should take a look on the Cocos 2D forums for your answer.  I tried searching for "draw colored line" in the Cocos2D forums...

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/search.php?q=draw+colored+line

Looks like it might be relevant to your situation.